# Javascript Bootbox Callback

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I am using bootbox for flexible dialogs and alerts asnd encountered a problem with following callback function:

```
var qty= 0;
bootbox.prompt({
title: "Insert qty!",
inputType: 'number',
callback: function (result) {
             qty = result;
          }
});

alert(qty);
```

My alert triggers before the bootbox dialog is opened.
Why is the alert triggered before the bootbox dialog?
How can I avoid getting 0 instead of a desired value in my bootbox-dialog?

Comment: did you try what i suggested?

Comment: I need that data to be processed again, do I have to enter all the long codes into the callback function?

Comment: thats an additional question - you may want to edit your question stating that you need that value for later processing. basically you shouldn't need to put your other functions that process the quantity inside the callback since the value is populated already and available outside of the function-scope..

Comment: Since you are new to SO I have follwing advice for you: If an answer helped you solve your issue stated in your question, you can use the checkmark to flag that answer as accepted..

Comment: This is mentioned in [the docs](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-notes) and in [Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#methods) - Bootbox functions can't block

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```
    bootbox.prompt({
        title: "Insert qty!",
        inputType: 'number',
        callback: function (result) {
         qty = result;
        }
    }, function (qty) {
       alert(qty);
    })
```

Comment: You basically copy and pasted my answer 10 minutes after i posted mine and then got the accepted flag - nice move..

Answer (score 3):

Put the alert within the callback like:

```
var qty= 0;
bootbox.prompt({
title: "Insert qty!",
inputType: 'number',
callback: function (result) {
         qty = result;
         alert(qty);
      }
});
```

That should solve your issue ;)

Comment: I need that data to be processed again, do I have to enter all the long codes into the callback function?